# Twitter contest for 3-day passes to New York Comic Con 2012

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Stack Exchange is giving away 5 3-day passes to [New York Comic Con](http://www.newyorkcomiccon.com/) via Twitter. Here’s what you have to do to enter the giveaway:

- Follow the [@StackSciFi](https://twitter.com/stackscifi) Twitter account. Winners will be contacted via Direct Message on Twitter, and the only way for contact to be made is if participants follow @StackSciFi.
- Think of a friend/fellow NYCC attendee/attending comic book writer/artist/internet celeb/outernet celeb/person.
- Find a question at the [Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) that you think that person would find interesting, be able to answer, enjoy reading, or (in some cases) be interested in because they wrote/directed/starred in the actual subject of the question.
- Share the question with the person (by @'ing them) using the site’s handy dandy sharing tools.

[image]

- Use the hashtag **#nyccse** so we can track all the questions being shared in this giveaway.
- It's optional, but you can **also include the link to this very post** so that the person knows this is a super-fun-awesome contest that is giving away passes to New York Comic Con, and also to explain why you are tweeting a super-fun-awesome, relevant question to them.
- One randomly drawn entrant will also receive **[Avengers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0083SBJXS)** and **[The Dark Knight Rises](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004LWZWGK)** on Blu-Ray in addition to 1 3-day pass to NYCC.

Only questions shared by @StackSciFi followers with a buddy via Twitter with the hashtag #nyccse are valid entries into the giveaway. You may tweet as many questions to your friends and/or celeb crushes as you like; each tweet acts as an entry to the contest BUT only 1 3-day pass will be awarded per user. The names of 5 people will be drawn at random.

The winners will be notified via Direct Message and will have to provide a mailing address that we can send the 3-day pass to.

The contests starts immediately; **the deadline for entry is Friday, October 5th at 4:00 PM EDT/8:00 PM UTC**.

Also, only enter if you are 100% able to go to New York Comic Con. We want to make sure that the passes go to people that are excited to take in the spectacular spectacle that is NYCC.

Stack Exchange is only responsible for the 3-day passes. The winners must provide their own transportation and lodging arrangements because, again, you are only getting a 3-day pass to New York Comic Con out of this.

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I added a link to the NYCC website for convenience sake.